# Is every open set on $\mathbb{R}^n$ homeomorphic to an open set containing the ball $B_1(0)$ of radius $1$ centered at the origin?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

**Question:** Is every non-empty open set on $\mathbb{R}^n$ homeomorphic to an open set containing the ball $B_1(0)$ of radius $1$ centered at the origin?
ty
I think this must be true, but i'm struggling to prove it. Any ideas on how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Every open set contains an open ball $B_r(x)$. With a translation you can move $x$ to $0$ and with stretching by $1/r$ (if $r$ was not already $\geq 1$) you can make this ball big enough. Both of those operations are homeomorphisms of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: Trivially true. Your open set contains some ball $B(x,r)$ and there is a homeomorphism of $\mathbb R^{n}$ which maps  this ball, to $B_2(0)$.

Comment: The empty set is open.

Comment: I'm a novice at topology, but out of interest, what is a homeomorphism between $(0,1)\cup (2,3)\ $ and $\ (0,1)$ ?

Comment: @AdamRubinson Your sets are not homeomorphic (one is disconnected, the other is connected). But, for the OP, the answer is yes, as long as the given open set is not empty.

Comment: @AdamRubinson, there is none, but this is not what the question is asking. Both of them are homeomorphic to some set containing $B_1(0)$, for example $(-1,1)\cup(2,3)$ for the former and $(-1,1)$ for the latter.

Comment: Oh right yeah then this question is trivial.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry, I misread the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t $U \neq \emptyset$ be an open set and $a \in U$. By definition of open set we know that there exists $\epsilon \in (0,\infty)$ such that $a \in B_\epsilon (a) \subset U$. Then consider $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ such that

\begin{equation*}
f(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{(\mathbf{x} - a)}{\epsilon}.
\end{equation*}

Then $f$ is a homeomorphism and we have $f \left( B_\epsilon (a) \right) = B_1(0)$. So $U$ is homeomorphic whith $f(U)$ and $B_1(0) \subset f(U)$.

Comment: The fact that $a\in B_\epsilon(a)$ has nothing to do with the definition of open set. You left out the crucial fact that $B_\epsilon(a)\subset U$.

Comment: I was using the definition that a set $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open if for every $a \in U$ there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $a \in B_{\epsilon}(a) \subset U$, but yes I forgot to write the $\subset U$ part.

Answer (score 1):

Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t $U \neq \emptyset.$ Then $\ U\ $ can be written as the union of open balls:

$$ U = \bigcup\limits_{i} U_i$$

Now choose one of the open balls, $U_j,$ and shift all of $U$ so that the centre of $U_j$ is at the origin, and enlarge all of $U$ by a scale factor so that $U_j$ = $B_1(0).$

This transformed set, call it $U'$, contains $B_1(0)$ and is homeomorphic to the original set $U.$